# Send callback functions through IPC from forked child_process in nodejs

Tags: node.js, callback, ipc

I'm using `child_process` to fork some work on a system. I have to send some data from the child to the "father" and I'm doing it like this:

```
process.send({
    message: "some_stuff",
    some : stuff,
    cb: cb
});
```

Where `cb` is a defined callback. On the other side ("father"'s side), inspecting the message received gives `undefined` for `msg.cb`. Thus I guess there is something preventing me to send callbacks through IPC. Also stringifying it doesn't work. Is there a clean way to do this or should I build an infrastructure to support callbacks?

Thanks